# Difficulty running Go file

Tags: windows, go, google-home

I am stuck on this tutorial. Nothing happens every time that I navigate to where my file is located and I try the "go run populationapi.go" step. I made a file populationapi.go in my workspace which I already set as the GOPATH variable. I have a windows computer. Which of the three folders should it be in (bin, pkg, or src)? Any ideas about what's going wrong?

https://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-get-started-google-actions/how-to/2017/01/31?page=4

Comment: Maybe start with the official docs, like [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: Duplicate by the same user, no less.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable), the `GOPATH` variable should be set to the folder *containing* `bin`, `pkg`, and `src`.

Here is the example directory layout they give:

```
GOPATH=/home/user/go

/home/user/go/
    src/
        foo/
            bar/               (go code in package bar)
                x.go
            quux/              (go code in package main)
                y.go
    bin/
        quux                   (installed command)
    pkg/
        linux_amd64/
            foo/
                bar.a          (installed package object)
```

Comment: the only thing is that I remember reading that GOPATH should not be set to the GO folder but a different directory... I will give this a try though I must have misunderstood.

Comment: It shouldn't be set to your Go *installation* directory (that should be your `GOROOT`, not your `GOPATH`).

Answer (score 1):

**each go program is a package and it should be in the "src/package-name/main.go"
where as package-name is the directory name which is same as your package name**

in your case
it should be **"src/populationapi/main.go"**

or whatever package file name you choose

then go to the package directory and run the command **"run main.go"**

in the tutorial they used "ngrok" utility you need to download and run that to make it work